# Wrong SERVER NAME in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

First, I started the SQL Server Browser in SQL Server Configuration Manager, because it was stopped. No problem to that, done. Next I started the SQL Server Agent, but there was an error:

> "The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. . .".

I also fixed that in SQL Server Instance name properties. Then I successfully started the SQL Server Agent. Then, I tried to go and put the server name in SQL Server 2012..

BUT THERE'S STILL AN ERROR! I don't know what to do any more. The server name is default. `MSSQLSERVER` I tried to put `MSSQLSERVER`, `PCNAME\MSSQLSERVER`... error is still there. what should I do?

Comment: Check your System and Application event logs, there will be a detailed message that explains why the service failed to start.

Comment: @Dai Where can I find that?

Comment: "Cannot connect to MSSQLSERVER" error. is still there

Comment: If you only have one instance on your server and it is the default instance and listening on port 1433, then you don't need the SQL Server Browser service. It is only needed when you multiple instances listening on different ports. Why did you want to start the SQL Server Browser service. As @Dai siad what is in the event logs? These can be found by starting the Event Viewer app. What exactly are you a) trying to achieve and b) what is the actual problem with your setup

Comment: "Then, I tried to go and put the server name in SQL Server 2012" do you mean in sql server management studio? Is the actual SQL Server (not just the agent) started? Check services? You've started two services (browser and agent) which aren't required for a local connection. Start the actual SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

The `MSSQLSERVER` service is the **default**, un-named instance - which means you can connect to it using a server/instance name of:

- `.`
- `(local)`
- `localhost`
- `pcname`

The point is: it's the **unnamed** instance, so you **don't** have to specify any instance name like `MSSQLSERVER` at all